# Is it OK to use swiftUI in playground when submitting playground file for WWDC 2021 Scholarship?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-playground, wwdc

Is it OK to use SwiftUI in a playground when submitting the playground file for WWDC 2021 Scholarship?

So, Apple says they only accept the playground file, and it seems using SwiftUI makes me way easier to create a scene. But I'm not sure whether it is OK to do it, or will the tester grade me lower for using SwiftUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I used SwiftUI last year and am using it again this year.

Edit: I won this year, so I can say for sure that it's fine.

Comment: @SJLee btw you can see existing projects [here](https://github.com/wwdc/2020). Many of the accepted ones also used SwiftUI.